# C# - Timer.Stop() isn't working

Tags: c#

I make a call via client side to initiate the StopTickerTimer function which successfully calls the StopTickerTimer function but unfortunately doesn't actually stop the timer. The timer starts and works properly but I can't seem to understand why my timer isn't stopping. I've tried setting timer.Enabled = false. I've tried various solutions that I've found on here but nothing seems to work.

```
    public Timer timer = new Timer();
    private string jsonContents;
    private string currentTickerPlaylist;
    private int i = 0;
    private List<string> playlistTickers;

    public void StartTickerTimer(int seconds, string selectedPlaylist)
    {
        currentTickerPlaylist = selectedPlaylist;
        InitPlaylistTickerTimer(seconds);            
    }

    public void StopTickerTimer()
    {
        StopTimer();
    }

    private void InitPlaylistTickerTimer(int seconds)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(t_Tick);
        timer.Interval = seconds * 1000;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SetPlaylistTickerSettings();
        if (i >= playlistTickers.Count)
        {
            i = 0;
            Payload ticker = new Payload
            {
                ticker = playlistTickers[i]
            };
            Payload ticker2 = new Payload
            {
                payload = ticker
            };
            var json = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(ticker2);
            PutToSingular("url", json);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            Payload ticker = new Payload
            {
                ticker = playlistTickers[i]
            };
            Payload ticker2 = new Payload
            {
                payload = ticker
            };
            var json = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(ticker2);
            PutToSingular("url", json);
            i++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you possibly stopping the timer from a different thread than the one that started it?

Comment: What do you mean "via client side"?

Comment: your timer would have to either be static (shared across all users) or stored in session state to be accessed with a separate client request.  And what's the server side technology? mvc, web api, etc.

Comment: As is, we cannot determine what the problem might be, just guess. Please add more details

Comment: How many times are you calling `InitPlaylistTickerTimer`?  If more than once, then you have multiple tick events happening.

Comment: t_Tick event check if stopped first.

Answer (score -2):

You started your timer, but you are not calling your "StopTimer" anywhere in the code...

Comment: StopTickerTimer does exactly that

Comment: Who told you that? Because you read 1 file of the solution you think you read absolutely everything? The OP only posted a minimum part

Comment: Exactly. The OP didnt post his whole code, so I analised based on what was posted, I didnt use my crystall ball to guess that the code is being called